# Writing to AVRO using spark core in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, avro

I am newbie to Scala & Spark. I am trying to read a text file and write it to Avro using spark. Can someone help me on where I am going wrong?

PS: I want to use spark core

Thanks

Harsha

```
class MyRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[GenericData.Record])
 }
   }


object Write {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

val outPath = args(0)

    val sconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Avro")
    sconf.set("spark.serializer",     "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    sconf.set("spark.kryo.registrator", "MyRegistrator")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sconf)

    val schema = new Parser().parse(this.getClass.getClassLoader
      .getResourceAsStream("sample.avsc"))
     val user = sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice1/user/harsha/sample.csv");

   val withValues = user.map((x) => (new AvroKey(x), NullWritable.get))

    val writeJob = new Job()
    AvroJob.setOutputKeySchema(writeJob, schema)

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(writeJob, new Path(outPath))

    writeJob.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[AvroKeyOutputFormat[Any]])
    withValues.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(writeJob.getConfiguration)

  }
}
```

But I am getting below error-

```
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://nameservice1/user/harsha/sample.csv:0+84
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: hdfs://nameservice1/user/harsha/sample.csv:84+84
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO deprecation: mapred.tip.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.id
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.attempt.id
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.is.map is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.ismap
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO deprecation: mapred.task.partition is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.partition
15/11/16 15:59:10 INFO deprecation: mapred.job.id is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.id
15/11/16 15:59:11 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
15/11/16 15:59:11 INFO FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
15/11/16 15:59:11 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: java.lang.NullPointerException: in User null of User
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:296)
        at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.write(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:77)
        at org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyRecordWriter.write(AvroKeyRecordWriter.java:39)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1000)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:979)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in User null of User
        at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:145)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:58)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:290)
        ... 10 more
```

Here's My Schema file

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "User",
  "fields" : [ {
  "name" : "name",
  "type" : "string"
  }, {
      "name" : "st_num",
      "type" : "int"
    }, {
      "name" : "st_name",
      "type" : "string"
    }, {
      "name" : "apt_num",
      "type" : "string"
    }, {
      "name" : "price",
      "type" : "string"
    } ]
  }
```

Comment: Please write stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Updated error stack trace